# Getting ": Invalid URI "/services/data/v36.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id%2C%20Name%20FROM%20Account"]" jsforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to get Account information from Salesforce using jsforce REST API, but I am getting ": Invalid URI "/services/data/v36.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id%2C%20Name%20FROM%20Account"]" error.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the token to the end of the password:

```
    conn.login(SF_USERNAME, SF_PASSWORD + SF_TOKEN, (err, userInfo) => {
    if (err) {
     console.error(err);
    } else {
     console.log('User ID: ' + userInfo.id);
     console.log('Org ID: ' + userInfo.organizationId);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you add two extra lines of code in the node_modules of jsforce's connection.js javascript.

```
  
this.signedRequest = options.signedRequest && parseSignedRequest(options.signedRequest);
  if (this.signedRequest) {
    this.accessToken = this.signedRequest.client.oauthToken;
  ==>  this.version = this.signedRequest.context.environment.version.api || defaults.version;
  ==>  this.instanceUrl = this.signedRequest.client.instanceUrl || this.instanceUrl;
  }
```

Comment: even it can solve the problem adding anything on jsforce node_modules will not persistent across server, ci/cd pipeline etc. is it open issue to jsforce library ?